# How to replace all instance of one word with another in C#

Tags: c#

How to replace all instances of a word with another in C#?  Is there a `RegexOption` to specify replacing all instances like `/g` in Perl?

Perl:

```
$line = "Oranges and Apples.  Apples and Oranges";
$line =~ s/Oranges/Pears/g;
```

C#:

```
string line = "Oranges and Apples.  Apples and Oranges";
line = Regex.Replace(line, @"Oranges", "Pears", ????);
```

The part I'm missing is indicated by `????` in the C# snippet.

Comment: Why are you using the `@`?

Comment: Just a good habit for c# regular expressions.  Might need to later add \s or other regex pattern matching characters to string otherwise you need double backslash to escape first backslash

Comment: I see - given its a constant, I prefer to wait until I need it.

Comment: @NetMage, `@` can only be used for <del>constants</del><ins>literals</ins>, so that last comment makes no sense. And I too use `@""` all the time for regex patterns, Power Shell scripts, and other code-like strings, regardless of the presence of `\ `.

Comment: @Bill Moore, Don't ask to translate code. Ask how to do what you want to do. Fixed your question.

Comment: Looks ok to me.  First line of question says It all. Anyways, I was just getting confused because c# defaults to global substitution. I guess that means c# has a RegEx Option to specify replacing only the first match instead.

Comment: There is no `RegexOptions` to restrict the replacements, but the non-static version (use like `(new Regex("Oranges")).Replace("string","Pears",1)`) has a variation that takes an integer number of replacements to do.

Comment: @BillMoore @Ikegami Some people wear a belt and suspenders :) I was trying to say, given that its a constant string, I would hope if I make a change that adds a backslash I would know to also add the `@` prefix, or double the backslash. I like to be fully aware when I am programming, and if I am on so much autopilot that I don't notice/forget the way strings work in C#, I will have bigger issues soon enough.

Comment: @NetMage, Again, `@` can only be used for <del>constant strings</del><ins>string literal</ins>, so that makes no sense. /// Re "*Some people wear a belt and suspenders*", No, some people like writing readable code. Adding `@` provides a semantic clue that the string contains code or something similarly complex. So yeah, I use `@""` all the time for regex patterns, Power Shell scripts, and other code-like strings, regardless of the presence of `\ `.

Comment: Like a file path? No, I don't buy it.

Comment: What does that have to do with anything?

Answer (score 4):

In C#, the `Regex.Replace` function is implicitly global, so that is the equivalent of the `g` modifier in Perl. You don't need any `RegexOptions`since there are no other flags on the Perl substitution.

```
line = Regex.Replace(line, "Oranges", "Pears");
```

If you don't want the global behavior for some reason, you need to use an instance, rather than the static method:

```
 line = (new Regex("Oranges")).Replace(line, "Pears", 1);
```

But you should probably use `String.Replace()` for this specific case, since this isn't really a pattern:

```
line = line.Replace("Oranges", "Pears");
```

Comment: Hope you don't mind the edit. Feel free to roll back if you feel it was too much.